# Change disable attribute in react select with material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change disable attribute in select on button click in react application using material ui
My button code is:

```
<AsistButton variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>X</AsistButton>
```

and from select is:

```
<NativeSelect
    value={person}
    className={classes.margin}
    onChange={handleChangeSelect}
    input={<BootstrapInput name="person" id="person-customized-native-simple"/>}
    disabled
>
    <option value=""/>
    <option value={10}>Peter</option>
    <option value={20}>Alex</option>
    <option value={30}>Jon</option>
</NativeSelect>
```

what function I need to define to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should write a counter in state like:

```
state={disabled: false}
```

and the on click should turn this.state.disabled to true.

after that in the NativeSelect component set disabled to

```
disabled={this.state.disabled}
```